# How to suppress unscoped enum warning in custom namespace?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have some enums inside of my own namespace, yet I still get that annoying warning about "pollution in the global namespace". Why am I getting this error since they aren't even in the global namespace? How could I get rid of this warning? The exact warning is:

```
C26812, The enum type 'Adventure_Game::itemType' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).
```

I have the enum declarations in my namespace inside the header file like this:

```
namespace Adventure_Game {

    enum itemType { Consumable, Key };
    enum equipType { Unarmed, Weapon, Shield, Armor };

    struct invItem { string name = "(name)", desc = "(desc)"; itemType type; unsigned int amount = 0; float value = 0.0f; };
    struct invEquip { string name = "(name)", desc = "(desc)"; equipType type; float low = 0.0f, high = 1.0f, weight = 0.0f, value = 0.0f; bool equip = false; };

}
```

I tried using enum classes too, but I don't want to use them in this case because it would break everything, and I'd have to use static casts everywhere and it would just be a mess. I would really appreciate help on dealing with this annoying warning.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSVC warning C26812 is not from the C/C++ compiler. It's coming from the Static Code Analysis (`/analyze`) feature and specifically from the [C++ Core Guidelines Checker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers).

The "recommended solution" that the checker is telling you about is to use C++11 strongly typed enumerations. That said, you can just suppress the warning as the *C++ Core Guidelines* are just recommendations.

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4619 4616 26812)
// C4619/4616 #pragma warning warnings
// 26812: The enum type 'x' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).
```

> You could also create a custom ruleset through the UI mentioned on Microsoft Docs if you wanted, but most of the other rules are all sensible so I find the single warning suppression to be the easiest path.

Answer (score 0):

Make code more strongly typed by using using `enum class` instead of just `enum`. Plain enums are more error prone as the enumerators can be converted to `int` easily.

See: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#enum3-prefer-class-enums-over-plain-enums

https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1423015134/scoped-class-enums-fundamentals-and-examples

Comment: What if I actually do want the `enum` to be easily convertible to `int`? I use it to store values that I can then use in calculations.

Comment: `enum class` is sometimes worse than good old `enum`. The lack of implicit conversion to int requires writing (and maintaining) a boilerplate code. A better alternative in this case is to use unscoped `enum` combined with a `struct` that provides the scope - if having a scope is necessary.